# Description of norms on $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

How could one describe all possible norms on $\Bbb R$, if one views $\Bbb R$ as a $1$-dimensional vector space?

Comment: all different or do you considder equivalent tnorms the same?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: By positive homogeneity, it all depends on $\|1\|$.